# Compiling C-Type Grammar to Custom Assembly

Tags: parsing, compilation

The title pretty much sums it up. I have a homemade CPU with my assembly language called scratchy that I'd like to write code for more effectively, but I imagine there MUST be a smart place to start.

Comment: Try writing an LLVM backend. There's a nice tutorial: http://jonathan2251.github.io/lbd/

Comment: +1 just for being called Morgan Freeman.

Comment: +1 for the homemade CPU.

Comment: Interesting subject, but what exactly is the actual question?

Comment: Hey, what if I really AM Morgan Freeman?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As well as [LLVM](http://llvm.org/), as suggested in a comment by @SK-logic, you might want to look at the [portable C compiler](http://pcc.ludd.ltu.se/) (`pcc`), which is possibly simpler to write a backend for.

Good luck!